# tomcat produce exceptions when running deployed war file

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, websocket, java-7

During development I use tomcat plugging for maven: tomcat7-maven-plugin version 2.2
When I deploy war file to the remote host, tomcat throws errors. Here is the version of tomcat on the remote server:

```
root@vido:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps# sh /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/version.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /var/lib/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /var/lib/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.26
Server built:   Apr 1 2013 08:32:04
Server number:  7.0.26.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.8.0-29-generic
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.7.0_55-b13
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

Here is java version:

```
root@vido:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps# java -version 
java version "1.7.0_55"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode)
```

Here is a part of pom.xml file:

```
    <!-- web sockets -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- servlets -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Here are exceptions:

```
DEBUG [pool-2-thread-1] (AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor.java:186) - Failed to class-load type while reading annotation metadata. This is a non-fatal error, but certain annotation metadata may be unavailable.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.visitEnd(AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor.java:182)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readAnnotationValues(ClassReader.java:1788)


DEBUG [pool-2-thread-1] (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:404) - Ignoring bean class loading failure for bean 'getDataHandler' 
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.vm.controllers.GetDataHandler] for bean with name 'getDataHandler' defined in file [/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/videomessenger/WEB-INF/classes/com/vm/controllers/GetDataHandler.class]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/vm/controllers/GetDataHandler : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class com.vm.controllers.GetDataHandler)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1330)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1396)
```

There are more errors but all of them of described type above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved by installing tomcat v 7.0.53

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are building a web app based on the JEE 7 specs, I can see the WebSocket api, While your dependency is for the JEE 6. Add the correct dependency for JEE 7 and the error will be removed. The error is due to its not able to find the class. Due to dependency mismatch its showing a version mismatch error too.